# JPA Criteria for MAX id GROUP BY FOREIGN KEY in a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, subquery, jpa-criteria

I'm developing an application using `Spring Boot` and `Spring Data JPA`.

The following are the relevant entities:

```
@Entity
public class Certification {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "certification_type_id")
    private CertificationType certificationType;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "certification", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<CertificationStatus> certificationStatuses;
}
@Entity
public class CertificationType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Code code;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    ...
    public enum Code {
        ...
    }
}

@Entity
public class CertificationStatus {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "certification_id")
    private Certification certification;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "certification_status_type_id")
    private CertificationStatusType certificationStatusType;
    private String remarks;
}

@Entity
public class CertificationStatusType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Code code;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "certificationStatusType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<CertificationStatus> certificationStatuses;
    
    public enum Code {
        ...
    }
}
```

In my service, I have a method, `CertificationService.findAll()`. The idea is to retrieve `certification` records whose latest `certification_status` is based on `MAX(id)`, `GROUP BY certification_id` and `WHERE certification_status_type_id = ?`. This method has five (5) parameters:

```
Integer certificationTypeId,
Integer certificationStatusTypeId,
LocalDate dateFrom,
LocalDate dateTo,
String client
```

The combination could be zero (0) to five (5). Thus, I chose to apply JPA Criteria. So far, I have coded the following:

```
@Override
public List<CertificationDto> findAll(
        Integer certificationTypeId,
        Integer certificationStatusTypeId,
        LocalDate dateFrom,
        LocalDate dateTo,
        String client) {
            
    var certifications = this.certificationRepository.findAll((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        var predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
        // This is working
        if (certificationTypeId != null && certificationTypeId > 0) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join(Certification_.certificationType, JoinType.INNER), certificationTypeId)));
        }

        // To do
        if (certificationStatusTypeId != null && certificationStatusTypeId > 0) {
            /*
             * I have no idea how to apply my SQL statement:
             * SELECT * FROM certification_status WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM certification_status GROUP BY certification_id) and certification_status_type_id = ?;
             */
             
             // Not sure what is the direction of the ff codes
            var certificationStatuses = root.join(Certification_.certificationStatuses);
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.max(certificationStatuses.get(CertificationStatus_.id)))); 
            // It says Cannot resolve method 'and(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<N>)'
            // Not also sure how to pass in parameter certificationStatusTypeId
        }

        // This is working
        if (dateFrom != null) {
            var offsetDateTimeFrom = OffsetDateTime.of(dateFrom, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, ZoneOffset.ofHours(8));
            var dateTimeFrom = Date.from(offsetDateTimeFrom.toInstant());
            var offsetDateTimeTo = OffsetDateTime.of(Objects.requireNonNullElse(dateTo, dateFrom), LocalTime.MAX, ZoneOffset.ofHours(8));
            var dateTimeTo = Date.from(offsetDateTimeTo.toInstant());
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.between(
                    root.get(Certification_.createdAt),
                    criteriaBuilder.literal(dateTimeFrom),
                    criteriaBuilder.literal(dateTimeTo)))
            );
        }

        // This is working
        if (client != null && !client.isBlank()) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.join(Certification_.client).get(Client_.name)), "%" + client.toLowerCase() + "%")));
        }

        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    });
    return certifications.stream()
            .map(this.certificationMapper::fromEntityToDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
}
```

My criteria for `certificationTypeId`, `dateFrom`, `dateTo`, and `client` are working. For the `certificationStatusTypeId`, I want to create criteria based on the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM certification_status WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM certification_status GROUP BY certification_id) and certification_status_type_id = ?;
```

This statement is working in the database. Not sure though if this is the best composition of query to select the record based on `MAX(id)`, `GROUP BY certification_id` and `WHERE certification_status_type_id = ?`.

Appreciate any help. Thank you.

**Update

This is now my code:

```
    if (certificationStatusTypeId != null && certificationStatusTypeId > 0) {
        Subquery<Long> subQuery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
        Root<CertificationStatus> subRoot = subQuery.from(CertificationStatus.class);
        subQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.max(subRoot.get(CertificationStatus_.id)))
                .groupBy(subRoot.get(CertificationStatus_.certification).get(Certification_.id));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.in(subRoot.get(CertificationStatus_.id)).value(subQuery)));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(subRoot.get(CertificationStatus_.certificationStatusType).get(CertificationStatusType_.id), certificationStatusTypeId)));
    }
```

But it throws the following error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.id' [select generatedAlias0 from entity.Certification as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias1.id in (select max(generatedAlias1.id) from entity.CertificationStatus as generatedAlias1 group by generatedAlias1.certification.id) ) and ( generatedAlias1.certificationStatusType.id=2 )]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.id' [select generatedAlias0 from entity.Certification as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias1.id in (select max(generatedAlias1.id) from entity.CertificationStatus as generatedAlias1 group by generatedAlias1.certification.id) ) and ( generatedAlias1.certificationStatusType.id=2 )]
```

Looking at the generated JPQL, it seems it looks similar to my SQL statement. I just don't understand why it's `Invalid path`.

**Update
My apologies! My SQL statement is actually similar to the following:

```
select
    // props of Certification
from certification c
inner join certification_type ct on ct.id = c.certification_type_id
inner join client cl on cl.certification_id = c.id
inner join certification_status cs on cs.certification_id = c.id
inner join certification_status_type cst on cst.id = cs.certification_status_type_id
where cs.id in (select max(cs2.id) form certification_status cs2 group by cs2.certification_id) and cs.certification_status_type_id = ?;
```

**Update**

This is solved. Thanks to `Thorben Janssen` for being patient looking into my issue.

This is the final portion of my codes:

```
    if (certificationStatusTypeId != null && certificationStatusTypeId > 0) {
        var certificationStatuses = root.join(Certification_.certificationStatuses);
        Subquery<Long> subQuery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
        Root<CertificationStatus> subRoot = subQuery.from(CertificationStatus.class);
        subQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.max(subRoot.get(CertificationStatus_.id)))
                .groupBy(subRoot.get(CertificationStatus_.certification).get(Certification_.id));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(certificationStatuses.get(CertificationStatus_.id).in(subQuery)));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(certificationStatuses.get(CertificationStatus_.certificationStatusType).get(CertificationStatusType_.id), certificationStatusTypeId)));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet creates a CriteriaQuery that's identical to your SQL statement. Because you're using Spring Data JPA, you can ignore the first block and the last line. Spring Data JPA provides them for you.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CertificationStatus> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(CertificationStatus.class);
Root<CertificationStatus> root = criteriaQuery.from(CertificationStatus.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root);

Subquery<Long> sub = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
Root<CertificationStatus> subRoot = sub.from(CertificationStatus.class);
sub.select(cb.max(subRoot.get("id")));
sub.groupBy(subRoot.get("certification").get("id"));

criteriaQuery.where(root.get("id").in(sub));

em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

You can [create a subquery](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-subquery-criteriaquery) by calling the `subquery` method on your `CriteriaQuery`. This returns a `Subquery` interface which you can use in the same way as the `CriteriaQuery` interface.

After you defined your `Subquery`, you can define the IN clause and include it in the WHERE clause of your query. This is the part that always looks a little strange. Instead of using the `CriteriaBuilder` to define the `Expression`, you get the entity attribute and call the `in` method on it with a reference to your `Subquery`.

In the final step, you use the `CriteriaQuery` to instantiate a `TypedQuery` and execute it. After you activated the [logging of SQL statements](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-logging-guide), you can see that Hibernate executes the following SQL statement:

```
select
    certificat0_.id as id1_4_,
    certificat0_.certification_id as certific3_4_,
    certificat0_.certification_status_type_id as certific4_4_,
    certificat0_.remarks as remarks2_4_ 
from
    CertificationStatus certificat0_ 
where
    certificat0_.id in (
        select
            max(certificat1_.id) 
        from
            CertificationStatus certificat1_ 
        group by
            certificat1_.certification_id
    )
```

**Update

It looks like you're referencing the wrong table when defining the IN clause. Please try to replace

```
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.in(subRoot.get(CertificationStatus_.id)).value(subQuery)));
```

with

```
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(certificationStatuses.get(CertificationStatus_.id).in(subQuery)));
```

Comment: My bad! The SQL statement I posted is just part of bigger statement. My `select ... from` is actually for the main entity, `Certification`. See my entities. I'll update my post.

Comment: I have updated my post. The result should be a list of `Certification`. Given the relationship `@ManyToMany`, list of `CertificationStatus` would be included.

Comment: It looks like you're referencing the wrong Root interface when creating the IN clause. Please take a look at my update

Comment: Thank you! I updated the codes based on your suggestion. It gave me an idea to also update the next line: `predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(subRoot.get(CertificationStatus_.certificationStatusType).get(CertificationStatusType_.id), certificationStatusTypeId)));` to `predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(certificationStatuses.get(CertificationStatus_.certificationStatusType).get(CertificationStatusType_.id), certificationStatusTypeId)));`. It is now working like a charm.